# Not returning desired output in fitdistr function

Tags: r

I have this code here, i'm trying to fit a weibull distribution using `fitdistr` from the `MASS` package, but I get the following message:

```
fitdistr(means[1], densfun="weibull")
Error in stats::optim(x = 0.153582646213799, par = list(shape = NA_real_,  :
non-finite value supplied by optim

means[1] = 0.154
```

What does this mean?
Is there any reason why I get this error and how should I avoid it? I don't have much background on the statistics and don't know what that means.

Comment: I am guessing the function `fitdistr` is from `library(MASS)`..

Comment: hi akrun, yes, yes it is

Comment: Please check this post `https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-December/183385.html` .  It seems to have some discussion about the issue (I haven't read it completely)

Comment: If your looking for a statistical explantion, perhaps you want to post this on http://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: akrun, thanks, it looks ok but how do i implement it in my fitdistr, which is weibull?

Comment: Maybe you are asking the function too much. I mean you want it to estimate the two parameters of the distribution using only one point. Did you mean to use the whole `means` vector?

Comment: @alko989 yes, i need the whole means vector, but still, if i try it with one value still doesn't work

Comment: That is my point, one data point is not enough to estimate two parameters. You need more data.